# What does the archetype of the shonen protagonist look like and how would the male and female versions look different?

Tags: archetypes

I'm writing a book called successors which tackles the entire world and it features 6 main protagonists and a lot of secondary characters. The one this question focuses on is named Xu. I want to write her as a shonen protagonist but replace the full idiocy with impulsiveness and make her kind of a wacko from not seeing many people. I want her to be like your Gokus, your Narutos, your Luffys and such.

I want Xu to be pretty much a stock shonen character, but I know female characters must be somewhat differently written than males. I want whoever answers, and don't hold back (go as in depth as possible), what would be the differences between a male or female shonen protagonist? Please use examples. I'm being very explicit about this because I want to do this correct and make the connection clear enough.

Answer (score 2):

Shōnen (jap. for "boy") are manga that are written for teenage boys. (Manga written for teenage girls are Shōjo.) Of course girls read Shōnen manga, too, but their target audience are teenage boys and therefore the characters are primarily designed to appeal to teenage boys and not girls.

For that reason, the female characters in classical Shōnen manga are written to appeal to their male audience! While [the male protagonist](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/StockShonenHero) is:

- big-hearted
- a bit dumb
- gifted
- loyal
- part of a group of friends
- relentless
- righteous
- virtuous
- merciful

the female side-characters in classical Shōnen manga are typically one or several of the following:

- a token girl (that is, they are only there to be female)
- a friend of the hero
- the hero's girlfriend or love interest
- sexualized
- a teacher of the hero
- trying to emulate the hero (but never quite as good)
- gentle (in contrast to the more violent hero)
- just as strong
- a minor antagonist
- angry and vengeful

Those are the "archetypes". In more recent Shōnen, girls can be the protagonists / heroines, and all characters, boys and girls, are often more differentiated and complex and less stereotyped.